# How to make a subform with "Disabled" aspect

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been searching around MSDN but couldn't find anything that made my form with that shaded grey aspect!! You know, like if it was covered with a grey translucid plastic! Please, help me out.

Comment: Aren't you trying to disable all the controls within a form, instead of the whole form?

Answer (score 1):

On the Data tab of the container for the subform, change the Enabled to No.  This only changes the border and the title.

Next, you have to change each field in the subform to be disabled (Data tab, Enabled = No).  This leaves the column headings looking normal, but the fields will be gray.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think it will be too much of a trouble for such a detail. Thank anyway.